# Validate certificate for Docusign Connect with X509 certificate enabled

Tags: x509certificate, iis-8, docusignapi

I want to secure the connection from Docusign Connect to our https endpoint.

Support already pointed me in the right direction. I downloaded the certificate from [here](https://trust.docusign.com/) and enabled the "Sign Message with X509 Certificate" in my Docusign portal.

I'm using C# .NET 4.5.1 WebAPI hosted on IIS 8 (Windows Server 2012) as my http endpoint.

How do I validate the certificate on my side?

Comment: Since this question isn't DocuSign-specific, I've added the x509certificate tag to this question. In the meantime, I'd suggest you search StackOverflow for information on how to validate certificates -- there seems to be lots of information available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. On my WebAPI Controller I try to extract the certificate from the request like this: X509Certificate2 certificate = this.Request.GetClientCertificate(). The result is always null. Does the X509 cert. option work in the Docusign demo portal?