# DocuSign Connect X509 Certificate

Tags: docusignapi

I am implementing validation for connect service similar to the question [Validate certificate for Docusign Connect with X509 certificate enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921135/validate-certificate-for-docusign-connect-with-x509-certificate-enabled)

I have everything working as expected. My concern is the certificate that I downloaded and installed  is a DocuSign X509 Connect public certificate. When the option says "Sign Message with X509" which certificate is used to sign the message? Does DocuSign has corresponding private key to sign message?

Answer (score 1):

@Vishnul

The x509 certificate provided in the following link is the public key. You would provide your private key and give the certificate to your DocuSign Account Manager. He/she will be able to upload it , and enable that feature for you.

https://trust.docusign.com/certificates

Comment: Can you be more specific? I may be missing something here. Are you suggesting if we want to use Public/Private key auth for DocuSign Connect then we need to create a our own Public/Private key pair and send the private key to DocuSign and they upload to our account. On our server we validate the request for private key and verify it using our public key installed on the server.